# How to get element value from array after values have been pushed into it in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery and couldn't find apt answer to this problem.
I have declared an array and pushing values into it;

```
var array=new array();
 $.each($("input[name='allMedia']:checked"),                
         function () {      
         array.push(this.value); 
});
```

Output : array = 1,2,3,4.

Now, I want to fetch values from this 'array' so that I can mark the checkbox as checked if the array values matches the id of checkbox being selected currently.
For this, I'm running a loop

```
array.forEach(function(e) {
alert(00);                                                         
  if ('2' == e.id) 
      alert(01);
});
```

How do I match if 2 matches with the values that are present in the variable array, at any index? Please suggest.

Comment: Why `e.id`? The elements of the array are strings.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];  /* Your array values */

var id = "2";  /* Your reference ID value */

for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
    if(id == array[x]){
        alert("This's your array value "+array[x]);
    }
}
```